# creating my own image gallery grid using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm stuck on a problem, it's creating an image grid and I can't figure out how to start laying out items on the next line when I reach the end of the container. I'm aware I could use masonry but the problem with that is my gallery needs to be full width and with masonry, you get that 1px whitespace issue [masonry 1px issue](https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/387). and just using regular floats also won't work for me because my items have varying heights. any thoughts on how I could tackle this issue would be awesome

```
function layout() {
  var itemPos = 0;
  var itemHeight = [];

  $('.gallery__item-list .gallery__item').each(function(index) {
    itemHeight.push($(this).height());
    $(this).css({
      transform: "translate3d(" + itemPos + "px,0px,0)"
    });
    itemPos += $(this).width();
  });
}
```

css

```
.gallery__item,.grid-sizer {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
 .gallery__item,.grid-sizer {
  width: 50%;} }
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
 .gallery__item,.grid-sizer {
  width: 33.333%;}
 .gallery__item--body-posts{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
 } }
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
 .gallery__item,.grid-sizer {
  width: 25%;
 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set image width in percentage if that allows in your case. Suppose you have three images in a row you can set width:33% which will take the full width of a row. So according to count you should change the width of images. When you get first three images in row, next three will come in the second row.

I hope this solves your problem